# Does a cursor in Android reference columns from 0 or 1?

Tags: java, android

I am working with an SQLite Database and I am returning cursors successfully but I was wondering if a cursor references columns starting with 0 like arrays or just 1?

Comment: and you were not able to test that in code, nor google it, but ask it here?

Comment: I did google it. And I got a bunch of useless stuff.

Comment: too long to post it as comment, so see the answer. I know that we programmers are lazy but ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A cursor from a SQLite database in Android references columns from 0.

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea how you searched in Google, but from the official documentation of [Android Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)

> public abstract int getColumnIndex (String columnName) Since: API
>   Level 1
>
> **Returns the zero-based index for the given column name**, or -1 if the
>   column doesn't exist. If you expect the column to exist use
>   getColumnIndexOrThrow(String) instead, which will make the error more
>   clear. Parameters columnName  the name of the target column. Returns
>
> **the zero-based column index for the given column name**, or -1 if the column name does not exist.

And you were really not able to find that, but a bunch of useless stuff?

Answer (score 1):

The Android documentation states that the getColumnIndex method from a SQLite Cursor returns the zero-based index for the given column name, or -1 if the column doesn't exist.

If you expect the column to exist use getColumnIndexOrThrow(String) instead, which will make the error more clear.

In short, they start at 0.

Source:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)